# How can I generate Sequence Diagram from Visual Studio 2017 for C++ code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17, sequence-diagram

I need to generate Sequence diagram for C++ code in Visual Studio 2017.

I have searched online for the same, but could not find any extensions for Visual Studio 2017. Are there any tools available for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you can try https://www.sourcetrail.com 
Sourcetrail has extension for visual studio and can be used as standalone application